# How exactly does torch / np einsum work internally

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, numpy-einsum

This is a query regarding the internal working of `torch.einsum` in the GPU. I know how to use `einsum`. Does it perform all possible matrix multiplications, and just pick out the relevant ones, or does it perform only the required computation?

For example, consider two tensors `a` and `b`, of shape `(N,P)`, and I wish to find the dot product of each corresponding tensor `ni`, of shape `(1,P)`.
Using einsum, the code is:

```
torch.einsum('ij,ij->i',a,b)
```

Without using einsum, another way to obtain the output is :

```
torch.diag(a @ b.t())
```

Now, the second code is supposed to perform significantly more computations than the first one (eg if `N` = `2000`, it performs `2000` times more computation). However, when I try to time the two operations, they take roughly the same amount of time to complete, which begs the question. Does `einsum` perform all combinations (like the second code), and picks out the relevant values?

Sample Code to test:

```
import time
import torch
for i in range(100):
  a = torch.rand(50000, 256).cuda()
  b = torch.rand(50000, 256).cuda()

  t1 = time.time()
  val = torch.diag(a @ b.t())
  t2 = time.time()
  val2 = torch.einsum('ij,ij->i',a,b)
  t3 = time.time()
  print(t2-t1,t3-t2, torch.allclose(val,val2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably has to do with the fact that the GPU can parallelize the computation of `a @ b.t()`. This means that the GPU doesn't actually have to wait for each row-column multiplication computation to finish to compute then next multiplication.
If you check on CPU then you see that `torch.diag(a @ b.t())` is significantly slower than `torch.einsum('ij,ij->i',a,b)`  for large `a` and `b`.

Comment: So the takeaway is that, whenever it is possible, it is always preferable to use ```einsum``` for computational (and time) efficiency, and I can trust einsum to perform only the necessay computations? (For my case, I typically have to deal with 4D arrays and perform all sorts of such operations)

Comment: Generally speaking ```torch.einsum``` will not necessarily be the most efficient in memory and time (see https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html). There are project like opt_einsum (see https://optimized-einsum.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) that may give you a more efficient implementation.

Comment: I'll check them out.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for `torch`, but have worked with `np.einsum` in some detail years ago.  Then it constructed a custom iterator based on the index string, doing only the necessary calculations.  Since then it's been reworked in various ways, and evidently converts the problem to a `@` where possible, and thus taking advantage of BLAS (etc) library calls.

```
In [147]: a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [148]: b = a

In [149]: np.einsum('ij,ij->i', a,b)
Out[149]: array([ 14, 126, 366])
```

I can't say for sure what method is used in this case.  With the 'j' summation, it could also be done with:

```
In [150]: (a*b).sum(axis=1)
Out[150]: array([ 14, 126, 366])
```

As you note, the simplest `dot` creates a larger array from which we can pull the diagonal:

```
In [151]: (a@b.T).shape
Out[151]: (3, 3)
```

But that's not the right way to use `@`.  `@` expands on `np.dot` by providing an efficient 'batch' handling.  So the `i` dimension is the batch one, and `j` the `dot` one.

```
In [152]: a[:,None,:]@b[:,:,None]
Out[152]: 
array([[[ 14]],

       [[126]],

       [[366]]])
In [156]: (a[:,None,:]@b[:,:,None])[:,0,0]
Out[156]: array([ 14, 126, 366])
```

In other words it is using a (3,1,4) with (3,4,1) to produce a (3,1,1), doing the sum of products on the shared size 4 dimension.

Some sample times:

```
In [162]: timeit np.einsum('ij,ij->i', a,b)
7.07 µs ± 89.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [163]: timeit (a*b).sum(axis=1)
9.89 µs ± 122 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [164]: timeit np.diag(a@b.T)
10.6 µs ± 31.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [165]: timeit (a[:,None,:]@b[:,:,None])[:,0,0]
5.18 µs ± 197 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```